# how to call c# function in razor page with out redirect page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

[this goal page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/treeview-checkbox/)

as in the link above
I want to see the sub-object of the tree on the web, so if I press the ▶ button, I want to search the DB through efcore.

To solve this, I thought about how to execute a specific function in cshtml, but I realized that the problem is that even if the function is executed, there is no change in the view.
Whenever the ▶ button to view sub-items in the tree is clicked, I want to search for sub-items in the DB and update the view without page redirection.

I tried using the redirect method. it is not comfortable

cshtml

```
@if (Model.authority)
    {content }
```

cshtml.cs

```
public IActionResult OnPostChagneMainCategorySelect()
{
     return RedirectToPage("/MyPage/Leader", new
     {
         _selectionWorkState= workState,
         _selectionItem = searchingItems,
         _selectionMain = searchingCategorys,
     });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate the URL change or the page refresh completely?

Comment: @faso 
If it's not inconvenient, you can use it. It doesn't matter if the user doesn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the same page you are on you can use

```
return Page();
```

Comment: amazing hahaha  i don't know that ha thankyou

Comment: If this method is used, the value of when the tree structure checkbox is used is initialized.
 How can I pass the values ​​of the checkboxes as well?

Comment: This causes a full page refresh, if you want to keep the data you had on that page before, you'll need to pass it back to the server first